# Selecting elements which have been loaded onto the page with Jquery's .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-listener

I have two html files and a javascript file using Jquery 2.1.4. The js runs on file1.html:

**file1.html**

```
<html>
    <body id="body">
        <p>Some random text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**file2.html**

```
        <button id="btnNewButton">Test</button>
```

**javascript file**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<div id="containerName"></div>').appendTo("#body");
    $('#containerName').load("file2.html");
});
```

This visually works file, the button from file2 is added to file1, however if I try to add an event listener with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<div id="containerName"></div>').appendTo("#body");
    $('#containerName').load("file2.html");

    $("#btnNewButton").click(alert("test1"));
});
```

It appears that javascript can't find the new button by that ID and just alerts to the page when the page is ready.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is, and how i can fix it? I have looked at other questions and not found an answer that solves this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register the click event handler with the `complete` callback of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

[`.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
**url**
Type: String
A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
**data**
Type: PlainObject or String
A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
**complete**
Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

```
$('#containerName').load("file2.html", function() {
    $("#btnNewButton").on("click", function() {
        alert("test1");
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to have solved the problem perfectly, thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

you have to initialize event after file2.html loaded successfully (give callback to parameter two of load()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<div id="containerName"></div>').appendTo("#body");

 $('#containerName').load( "file2.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
    $("#btnNewButton").click(alert("test1"));
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('<div id="containerName"></div>').appendTo("#body");
     $('#containerName').load("file2.html");
     $(document).on("click","#btnNewButton",function() { 
                                                alert("test1");
                                            });
});
```

For earlier versions of jquery (prior to jquery 1.7)  instead of .on(), .live() was used to create event listeners for dynamically added elements.

Like this:

```
$("#btnNewButton").live("click",function(){alert("test1");});
```